# What's the difference between creating the Vue instance properties inside and outside the export default?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So in Vuejs, what is the difference between the two below?

1. Is it more advisable to do the first one?
2. Is it advisable to use the second one for other properties (methods, computed, watch, etc)?
3. What are the effects of using the second one for creating the properties?

Thank you for any input!

```html
<template>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
      return {
      .........
      }
    },

</script>
```

```html
<script>

let data = {
    .....
}

export default {
  data() {
    return data
  },
      
 </script>
```

Comment: It's a mistake to create `data` variable outside `data` function because it's supposed to be a new object for each component instance. This is the reason why `data` object was deprecated in favour of function

Comment: thank you! Now, I will always put ``data`` values inside ``data`` function itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630641/vue-chart-multiple-instance-initialization