# vue-chart multiple instance initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I would like to have multiple vue-chart.js graphs, each one refreshing (adding a new data point) every 5s. Value comes from a sensor and it is passed with props (I am writing UI for node-red application, which is I think not relevant to the problem).

I managed to get one graph working perfectly, but if I place 2 graphs, the passed values are displayed in both graphs simultaneously (not just in the one, that should diplay them).

See for youself here [working CodeSandBox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-6o5mf)

What puzzles me is, that the  `console.log(this.myChart)` in `adddata` shows "correct" graph (different `id`, different `context`). I think I have created individual graph instances and still, I can not add data to only one of those.

I do not use vue very offten, I may be missing something important. Thank you!

Component `Test.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas :id="name"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from "chart.js";

const chartSetting = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "setpoint",
        data: [],
        borderColor: "blue",
        borderWidth: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {},
};

let interval;

export default {
  name: "test",
  data() {
    return {
      myChart: null,
      chartSetting: chartSetting,
    };
  },
  props: ["id", "name", "setpoint"],
  methods: {
    adddata(setpoint, time) {
      this.myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(setpoint);
      this.myChart.data.labels.push(time);
      this.myChart.update();
      console.log(`now printing ${setpoint} to this graph:`);
      console.log(this.myChart);
    },

    createChart(chartId, chardData) {
      const ctx = document.getElementById(chartId);
      // Save reference
      this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chardData.type,
        data: chardData.data,
        options: chardData.options,
      });

      interval = setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date();
        let seconds = date.getSeconds();
        this.adddata(this.setpoint, seconds);
      }, 5000);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.createChart(this.name, this.chartSetting);
  },
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>
      graphs get new data from 2 different sensors every 5 seconds. Here
      simulated as "6" and "3"
    </p>
    <h3>this graph should only show 6</h3>
    <test name="grap1" id="1" setpoint="6" />
    <h3>this graph should only show 3</h3>
    <test name="grap2" id="2" setpoint="3" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test from "./components/Test";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Test,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chartSetting` object is the same for all component instances because it's defined once when component module is evaluated.

The reason `data` is factory function is that it returns a new data object for each instance that isn't shared between instances.

It should be:

```
  data() {
    const chartSetting = ...

    return {
      myChart: null,
      chartSetting: chartSetting,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Yes, looks about right, thank out! I was treating the `chartSetting` like a simple not-that-important initialization object containing color setting and stuff... but it actually holds the data as well...